# Элементы не сплывают влево (float:left)

Tags: css, float

Возможно решение здесь очень простое, но я уже много чего попробовал, и толку нету. Нужно чтобы список и соц кнопки были в одной строке, пытался задавать флоаты для них отдельно, но тоже не работает, не понимаю в чем дело. Менял обертку для соц кнопок с блочного на строчный элемент, но тоже ничего. Еще список растягивался на всю страницу, думал в этом дело, поставил ему ширину и макс ширину, но также эффекта нет. Нужен опытный глаз и пояснение, чтоб на будущее знал)

Код

```css
a[href*='face'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3b5998;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a[href='http://facebook.com']:hover {
  /*color: black*/
  ;
}

a[href*='telegram'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0099e5;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a[href*='twitter'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0088cc;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div {
  float: left;
  /* display: inline; */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Terms</li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
    <li>About</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="socials2">
    <a href='https:twitter.com' class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook-square" target='_blank'></a>
    <a href='http:telegram.org' class="fa fa-telegram" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: изучите flexbox. Очень удобный и современный инструмент по сравнению с float, гораздо удобнее и функциональнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с `flex`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a[href*='face'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3b5998;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a[href='http://facebook.com']:hover {
  /*color: black*/
  ;
}

a[href*='telegram'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0099e5;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a[href*='twitter'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0088cc;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Terms</li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
    <li>About</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="socials2">
    <a href='https:twitter.com' class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook-square" target='_blank'></a>
    <a href='http:telegram.org' class="fa fa-telegram" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с `float`:

**P.S.** Обёртку на 100% ширину, чтобы она растягивалась, затем указываем `float: left` для списка, `float: right` для иконок.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  float: left;
}

.socials2 {
  float: right;
}

a[href*='face'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3b5998;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a[href='http://facebook.com']:hover {
  /*color: black*/
  ;
}

a[href*='telegram'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0099e5;
  font-size: 30px;
}

a[href*='twitter'] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0088cc;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Terms</li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
    <li>About</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="socials2">
    <a href='https:twitter.com' class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook-square" target='_blank'></a>
    <a href='http:telegram.org' class="fa fa-telegram" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам помог ответ - отметьте решением и поставьте плюс

Answer (score 1):

```css
a[href*='face'] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3b5998;
font-size: 30px;
}

a[href='http://facebook.com']:hover {
/*color: black*/;
}

a[href*='telegram'] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0099e5;
font-size: 30px;
}

a[href*='twitter'] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0088cc;
font-size: 30px;
}

div {
 display: flex;
 /* display: inline; */
}

ul {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Terms</li>
  <li>Contacts</li>
  <li>About</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="socials2">
  <a href='https:twitter.com' class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook-square" target='_blank'></a>
  <a href='http:telegram.org' class="fa fa-telegram" target="_blank"></a>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Через `float` тогда это свойство нужно применять к списку и блоку с соцальными иконками.
2. Через `flex` тогда блоку-обертке со значением `display: flex`, если нужно чтоб пункты меню тоже были в 1 линию, пропишите `display: flex` для списка

Answer (score -1):

```css
a[href*='face'] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3b5998;
font-size: 30px;
}

a[href='http://facebook.com']:hover {
/*color: black*/;
}

a[href*='telegram'] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0099e5;
font-size: 30px;
}

a[href*='twitter'] {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0088cc;
font-size: 30px;
}

div {
 float:left;
 /* display: inline; */
}
.menu{
  width:100%;
}
.menu ul li{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li>Terms</li>
  <li>Contacts</li>
  <li>About</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="socials2">
  <a href='https:twitter.com' class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook-square" target='_blank'></a>
  <a href='http:telegram.org' class="fa fa-telegram" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

А вообще в данный момент float-ы не очень удобная вещь по сравнению с flexbox.
Вот статья, если интересно:
http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/

Comment: флоаты нормально удобные, если понимать принцип работы

Comment: @slowBro, и уметь ими пользоваться:)

Comment: @St1myL я это и имел введу

Comment: как то пропустил флексбоксы во время обучения, но все же интересно, почему флоаты даже вот так не работают? - https://jsfiddle.net/yupra023/12/

Comment: само определения float(например right) означает не только то что элемент плывет вправо а то что это элемент будет обтекаться соседними элементами слева. В твоем пример картинка просто не хватает ширины окна для картинки и списка. увеличь ширину экрана или уменьши ширину картинки и все заработает . тут нормально описано http://htmlbook.ru/css/float

Comment: спасибо всем, уже разобрался, в первоначальном примере нужно было просто добавить float для ul, тогда все работает, но flexbox обязательно изучу